# Is it worth caching a member struct?

Tags: c#, caching, struct, value-type

I have a property that goes something like this:

```
DateTime MinDate
{
    get { return new DateTime(2005, 3, 25); }
}
```

My concern is that calling `Derived.MinDate` will construct a new `DateTime` every time it is called, so I'm looking to have an underlying `_MinDate` that is only constructed once.

```
private readonly DateTime _MinDate = new DateTime(2005, 3, 25);

DateTime MinDate
{
    get { return _MinDate; }
}
```

But does this have any impact at all, since `DateTime` is a struct anyways? **Scenario 1:** `MinDate` constructs a new `DateTime`, which is then copied to the caller. **Scenario 2:** `_MinDate` is copied to `MinDate`, which is copied to the caller. Both situations are equally as inefficient, right?

Comment: Are you expecting to make millions of these objects?

Comment: No, the second example is more efficient as the JIT will inline the property getter and thus eliminate the second copy operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, the `DateTime(Int32, Int32, Int32)` constructor is very cheap: it performs a trivial multiplication operation to convert years, months and days to internal 64-bit "Tick" values.

AFAIK the CLR does not cache deterministic struct constructor instances (but it would be a nice optimization!).

However, I would only cache this value if you're calling the constructor hundreds of times every second, but if you really want to, then this works:

```
private static readonly DateTime _minDate = new DateTime( 2005, 3, 25 );
protected override DateTime MinDate { get { return _minDate; } }
```

Answer (score 4):

Almost correct; there is very little reason to do that.

By caching the struct, you'd need to copy the bytes of the cached value.

By constructing it, you need to call the constructor, which will set the struct's fields.

If the constructor does expensive work, caching may be useful.

The [DateTime constructor](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,176) does a fair bit of work, so if you call that property many times, it might be worth it.
However, you should only do this if you actually see performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

As of C# 6.0, there is now an easier way to do this with auto-implemented property initializers:

```
DateTime MinDate { get; } = new DateTime(y, m, d);
```

**EDIT:** This is actually an intended use of the feature, and the backing field is automatically made `readonly` by the compiler; in fact, you can do a `set` operation on them within the constructor. They're called "getter-only auto-properties." See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about the concept of being copied when passed to another variable, because the DateTime is a struct.

Here is one way of achieving what you are after:-

```
abstract class Base
{
    protected abstract void GetMinDate (ref DateTime minDate);
}

class Derived
{
    private static readonly DateTime _MinDate;
    static Derived()
    {
       _MinDate = new DateTime(2005, 3, 25);
    }
    protected override void GetMinDate (ref DateTime minDate);
    {
        minDate = _MinDate;
    }
}
```

The GetMinDate will always return the minimum date by ref and it will be the callers issue to copy or not to copy.

Comment: +1 for thinking of a workaround to the (although small) performance overhead; this would definitely be useful when dealing with large structs.